# How to rotate an image until collision is detected

Tags: java, android, android-animation, collision-detection

So i have this code that rotates an imageView around a point near the center of the screen

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,0,135);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setDuration(2000);
image.startAnimation(anim);
```

I also have this code that checks for a collision between that image and another one

```
Rect rc_img1 = new Rect();
image.getDrawingRect(rc_img1);

Rect rc_img2 = new Rect();
image2.getDrawingRect(rc_img2);

if (Rect.intersects(rc_img1, rc_img2)) {

}
```

How would i do some sort of loop that keeps rotating the image until the collision is detected, which it will then stop rotating. I cant seem to figure this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use boolean flag to check if the image has collided, if not keep rotating. It may not work but I think it worth to try.

```
if (Rect.intersects(rc_img1, rc_img2)) {
    isCollided = true;
}
```

Comment: How would i have it continuously check if it has collided while the image is rotating

Comment: Just experimenting, can you try anim.cancel() or anim.reset() in your intersects ? I assumed that your if block is in a loop.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html

Comment: right but how would it keep checking for the intersects while the animation is occuring? thats what is confusing me.

Comment: @Jake Look to my answer. I combine an ObjectAnimator and add an UpdateListener. You can check on the onAnimationUpdate()-Method if the 2 views are collided. I hope this will work for you. Let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an ObjectAnimator with an UpdateListener and check if the views are collided in the update method.

```
// Generate RotationAnimator
final ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotationY", 0.0f, 360f);
animation.setDuration(5000);
animation.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
// Add Update Listener
animation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
               // Check if collision
               if(isCollided){
                   animation.cancel();
               }
            }
        });

animation.start();
```

Comment: Does it work for you? The updatelistener is perfect for your stuff